# Make servers redundant

Tags: php, linux, webserver, vps, synchronous

I have created a php project which needs to run 27/7. Really 0,00% downtime. 
Therefore I would like to buy 3-5 VPS. 
Now my question is: how to get them running synchronously? Maybe there is another solution for that?

Thanks!

Comment: AWS .. load balancing .. probably a better question for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: You could use a load balancer or keepalived to distribute the workload in case one server crashes, set up multiple database servers with replication, use multiple servers on separate networks and in separate countries, and so on. But you **will** have downtime eventually; someone will break a DNS server, your load balancer will crash, or something else you have no control over will go wrong. 0.00% downtime is a myth.

Comment: Okay thx for the answers, is 0,00% is really not possible? How does Google and others do that?